# What is the equivalent to AssociationType in Entity Framework Core 2?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I use a convention (IStoreModelConvention) where I need to know if AssociationType.IsForeignKey is true. The objective is to rename all foreign keys in mapped tables. For example, remove the underscore and compose a totally new name derived from the classes and properties names.

The question is: exists a equivalent to AssociationType.IsForeignKey in Entity Framework Core  2 or how can i accomplish this type of customization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF Core 2 has different (or better) naming system for ForeignKeys. The name is constructed as `FK_Table_ReferencedTable_FKProperties` where Table is where the FK constraint is defined. ReferencedTable is principal side. And FKProperties is `_` separated list of foreign key properties. Perhaps it would match up the naming system you want.

Though if you want to still customize the names of foreign key properties, then in ef core there are no user defined convention support yet. But EF Core allows you to iterate over model metadata to configure it the way you want. In your `OnModelCreating` method in derived `DbContext` you can put following code to name FK as you want.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Configure model
    foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        foreach (var declaredForeignKey in entityType.GetDeclaredForeignKeys())
        {
            declaredForeignKey.Relational().Name = "<Construct_FK_Name>";
        }
    }
}
```

and a strongly-typed version below (with the "using" statement)

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;

        foreach (IEntityType entityType in this.entityDbContext.Model.GetEntityTypes())
            {
            foreach (IForeignKey declaredForeignKey in entityType.GetDeclaredForeignKeys())
            {
            }
        }
```